# InputSelect with "options" values from an API and a "current value" from another API will not work together

Tags: reactjs

I have this InputSelect:

```
<InputSelect           
    value={dataState.audit_area_name}
    options={auditAreas}
/>
```

**auditAreas** is coming from a react-query and shows my available options on my InputSelect. Everything works fine.

**dataState.audit_area_name** is also coming from a react-query and is set here:

```
// Update the displayed Data
useEffect(() => {
  if ((strategic_initiative) && (auditAreas && auditAreas.length > 0)) {
    dispatch({ type: "SET_DATA", data: strategic_initiative[0] });
  }
}, [strategic_initiative, auditAreas]);
```

The value **dataState.audit_area_name** is also shown correctly if I display it on a  element.

My Problem: The value dataState.audit_area_name is not shown correctly on my InputSelect. The value is 100% available in the options of the InputSelect.

My initial thought was: Okay, maybe the audit_area_name is passed before I pass the options, so I added this to get sure my auditAreas are here before I update my values:

```
if ((strategic_initiative) && (auditAreas && auditAreas.length > 0)) {
```

But it did not have any effect.

Why is my value not shown on my InputSelect, even if the data is 100% available in the options?

Edit: How I set my data

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
       case "SET_FIELD":
            return {
           ...state,
           [action.field]: action.value,
           };
       case "SET_DATA":
          return {
          ...state,
          ...action.data,
          };
       default:
           throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: 
               ${action.type}`);
           }
        }
```

Comment: first try to log its value

Comment: i did, everything is fine.

Comment: How are you setting `audit_area_name`? What does that code look like?

Comment: I have added the function of how I set the data. I have no problems with it. data will be set accordingly

Comment: What UI library are you using? Have you looked at the documentation for `InputSelect`?

Comment: how do you think its UI related? Its an internal corporate UI. everythink works fine if I pass the values in "options" manually, and not via an API

Comment: Nevermind. It works now. Was a strange database error. thanks for you time yall

Comment: @JohnDole Because obviously the implementation of `InputSelect` is what determines how it behaves in different scenarios. Not showing that part of the code is like asking "why is this black box outputting abc when I input xyz".